# A Script to Edit Code (RegEx?)

Tags: regex, javascript, replacement

this is my first post on SuperUser and I'm unaware if I'm in the right place.

I have written a game in JavaScript. Throughout the game, I use FOR loops in the following fashion for a miriad of tasks.

```
for([variable] = [value]; [variable] < [array].length; [variable]++)
```

However, for optimization purposes, I'd like to change every single FOR loop of this fashion into a slightly different format

```
let len = [array].length
for([variable] = [value]; [variable] < [array].length; [variable]++)
```

Essentially, a glorified find-and-replace. Is there any way I could create some kind of script to do this?

EDIT: I've looked into using RegEx, but my trouble is that all the variables can be any length.

Comment: @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT it's not Java code related, as it could apply to any high level code.. But it is code related. From a refactoring perspective it could be seen as Java related

Answer (score 0):

The following RegEx, will match all the line and extract the variable name, the value, and the array name:

```
for *\( *([\w$]+) *= *([^;]+); *[\w$]+ *< *([\w$]+).length *; *[\w$]+\+\+ *\)
```

If your RegEx parser supports back references (JavaScript's one does), then the pattern can be shortened and reinforced by replacing the next variables patterns by a back reference to the first variable occurrence. This guaranty that the statements will match only if the variable name is the same for all occurrences:

```
for *\( *([\w$]+) *= *([^;]+); *\1 *< *([\w$]+).length *; *\1\+\+ *\)
```

Extracted values:

- 1st group: variable name
- 2nd group: value
- 3rd group: array name

From these values, the matched line can easily be rewritten in the target form.

Remark: To be fully JavaScript compliant and allow spaces, tabs and line breaks in the 'for' statement, all  `*` occurrences should be replaced by `\s*`.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0_9_$]+` matches letters, `0` or `9` or `_` or `$` why don't you want to match digits between `1` and `8` ? I guess it's a typo. And why are you matching `$`? There're no `$` sign in JavaScript variable name.

Comment: @Toto: Sorry, I typed the expression on my smartphone and made a mistake. You are right for the digits. The valid pattern is `0-9`, and not `0_9`. I fix it. But for the dollar sign, you are wrong. The dollar sign is perfectly valid in JavaScript. It's like an underscore, no more, not less.

Comment: You're right for `$` sign, my bad. But I've never seen that. Another comment, `[a-zA-Z0-9_$]` can be simplified as `[\w$]`

Comment: Yes Toto, you are right. In the same way it can also be shortened (and reinforced) by using back references for the variable name. I edited the answer to reflect that.